# C# Web Application Unable to Login on Chromioum

Tags: .net, chromium

I have a .NET web application with an out-of-the-box login method:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            ActionResult result;
            IRestResponse<Dictionary<string, string>> v = null;
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                LoggerService?.Log(new user_log("Logged in attempt failed from " + this.GetIPAddress(), "Unknown"));
                ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
                result = View(model);
                // otherwise return success
            }

            if(await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Username, model.Password, true, false) == SignInStatus.Success)
            {
                LoggerService?.Log(new user_log("Logged in", model.Username));
                result = RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            } else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("LoginReject", "Login Failed");
                ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
                result = View(model);
            }

            return result;
        }
```

Today trying to login on Chrome or Edge simply causes the page to reload with nothing sent to application and nothing in web console. SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync() returns SignInStatus.Success but Chromioum does not seem to see it this way. Firefox and even IE work fine. A clean Chrome reinstall does not help.

Has anyone else ran into this? Or has Google simply cast me out of it's garden?

Comment: Of all things a reboot fixed this